# Did I damage my car by trying to move in reverse with the handbrake on?

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, handbrake

I was in a hurry to leave for the office yesterday and forgot that my handbrake was engaged while starting. I started the engine, clutched, and reverse geared, and found the vehicle not moving backwards. I quickly depressed the clutch and retried. After these two attempts, I realized my error of not disengaging the handbrake.

I didn't step on the gas in the process of trying to move. I want to know if I have done any damage to my car.

Answer (score 6):

No significant damage has been done. There are two potential areas that can be damaged by extended driving with the park brake on. The park brake shoes/pads will wear prematurely if the vehicle is driven with the brake engaged. The clutch will also suffer some wear as the brake being on will require slipping/riding the clutch on every start. In your case you caused no more wear than would occur by starting on a hill.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know if I have done any damage to my car.

**No, you're fine.**

In this question, a user asked if driving 1000 meters with the handbrake on had caused permanent damage:

[I drove with the handbrake on for 1000 metres](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/8960/57)

Our assessment then was that that driver had probably caused plenty of wear to the handbrake but not damage.  Since you barely moved, you're almost certainly perfectly fine (if a bit embarrassed).

Answer (score 0):

You are 100% fine. I don't think the people replying read that you didn't even step on the gas at all when trying to move. You didn't list what car you were driving but I seriously doubt your car would be able to generate that much toque to even cause any wear to your handbrake just by riding the clutch friction point.