# Brand new 2022 Kia Forte GT

Tags: brakes, kia, forte

Just got a brand new car and I drove 5 miles to my locations and 5 miles back and when I put it in park that’s when the emergency brake light turned on I didn’t even see it on beforehand … but if I did drive with it on for 10 miles should I be worried ?

Comment: Does the emergency brake turn on automatically when you park?  It should tell you in the owners manual.

Comment: Many new cars automatically disengage the electric emergency brake when you start to drive.  Does your car do that?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Related: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/21668/6299 et al.

Answer (score 1):

On your vehicle the parking brake automatically disengages if you try and drive with it engaged. However, to engage the parking brake you must do this manually by stepping on the brake pedal and lifting the parking brake button found on the middle console.  So you have nothing to worry about as you did not damage anything.